# Передвигаться на инвалидной коляске или в инвалидной коляске?

Tags: выбор-слов

Передвигаться на инвалидной коляске или в инвалидной коляске?

Answer (score 1):

*В коляске*, поскольку коляска — это разновидность кресла (как правило, сидят *в кресле*, но *на стуле*). В некоторых контекстах — с акцентом на факт передвижения (гонка на колясках) — возможен альтернативный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Словарь рекомендует форму ***передвигаться в коляске***, но в текстах встречаются оба варианта. Кроме того, предлог В часто используется в выражениях ***находиться в коляске***, а предлог НА - в выражениях ***везти на коляске, ехать на коляске.***

ПЕРЕДВИГАТЬСЯ, 1. Перемещаться, двигаться с одного места на другое.  **Перемещать себя, своё тело с одного места на другое (о человеке, животном).** Старик мог п. только **в коляске.**

Передвигаться Керк мог теперь только **в инвалидной коляске**. [Григорий Свешников. Четыреста серий назад (1997) // «Столица», 1997.10.13] Также была приобретена парта, рассчитанная на детей, передвигающихся **в инвалидной коляске**. [«Новгородские ведомости», 2013]

Она была очень слаба...передвигаться могла только **на инвалидной коляске,** на которой и ездила из палаты на службы в часовню. [Е. Кучеренко. (2015.09.21)] Кроме того, Стиру было бы весьма непросто добраться до лагеря, ведь он **передвигается на инвалидной коляске.** [ 2003.03.03]

Comment: Мне кажется, "передвигаться на коляске" носит разговорный характер. – М_Г 21 час назад

Comment: По-моему, здесь влияет семантика и традиция. Передвигаются на машине, на велосипеде (вид транспорта), на телеге (она плоская), в розвальнях (санях). На коляске - это способ передвижения, в коляске - сидя в коляске. Пример: Кроме того, Стиру было бы весьма непросто добраться до лагеря, ведь он передвигается на инвалидной коляске.«Военный вестник Юга России» (Ростов-на-Дону), 2003.03.03]

Comment: Военная (+) журналистика - едва ли образцовый источник русского языка :)